# Release the lock on dlls picked up by MEF in a click once application

Tags: c#, wpf

How do I enable in my ClickOnce Application (WPF) such plugin dlls can be delted at runtime?

I have found an old demo that do it with this.

```
private static void SetShadowCopy()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyFiles();
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetCachePath(@"C:\MEF\PartUpdatesInPlace\PartUpdatesInPlace\bin\Debug\Cache");
}
```

But it yields warnings that it is obsolete and I should use something else but I cant figure out how to enable shadow copying when not doing like above.
The two lines works as expected. And I have seen people doing a shell exe application that startst he real application. I dont want that either.

I assume there must be a way to do the same as above but not using obsolete methods.

#### Update

```
        // Works
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetShadowCopyFiles();
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetCachePath(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Cache\");
     
        // Dont Work
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.CachePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Cache\";
```

The difference seems to be that SetShadowCopyFiles() works from the point its called and after, so when I setup the Mef Catalogs after this calls the dlls works and I can update dlls and do a container.refresh() without problems.

Using SetupInformation no cache folder is created and the dlls are locked.

#### Update 2

To others. This dont work for click once applications so far.

Comment: Updated my answer to modify the value through reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to MSDN, the alternative to [SetShadowCopyFiles()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setshadowcopyfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is [IAppDomainSetup.ShadowCopyFiles {get;set;}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomainsetup.shadowcopyfiles%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

You should just be able to set it to `true` and give the same functionality.

To use it, set the `ShadowCopyFiles` property on the SetupInformation. `AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles` is read-only.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
```

**EDIT:** It appears as though changing the SetupInformation after the domain has been created has no effect.

> AppDomainSetup Class: Changing the properties of an AppDomainSetup
>   instance does not affect any existing AppDomain. It can affect only
>   the creation of a new AppDomain, when the CreateDomain method is
>   called with the AppDomainSetup instance as a parameter.

I am unsure how you are supposed to do it now other than continuing with the obsolete methods and risking the fact that the next iteration of .NET may remove them.

**EDIT 2:** I played around with this a little bit and used dotPeek to see what the AppDomain was doing with the ShadowCopyFiles. I decided to see if I could set it through Reflection.

You may want to try the below and see if this does what you need. Setting it to true on the internal FusionStore property of AppDomain causes the `AppDomain.ShadowCopyFiles` property to reflect the change which was not the case when setting it on the exposed `SetupInformation.ShadowCopyFiles` property.

```
var setupInfoProperty = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetType().GetProperty("FusionStore", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance);
var setupInfo = (AppDomainSetup) setupInfoProperty.GetValue(AppDomain.CurrentDomain);
setupInfo.ShadowCopyFiles = "true";
setupInfo.CachePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + @"\Cache\";
```

Comment: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ShadowCopyFiles = true; gives the error that its readonly.

Comment: Well, poop. Let me see what else I can find. Got to love "documentation"

Comment: Its not because I have not been over the documentation, i just found it limited on this topic.

Comment: @pksorensen I don't get what you mean. I was more poking fun at MSDN for saying "use this now, but this isn't really how it is".

Comment: I was just saying that the msdn documentation didnt have the solution from what I found. It just directed me to what you also found and that didnt work.

Comment: @pksorensen The actual call is in the SetupInformation. I have updated my answer. I didn't catch that ShadowCopyFiles was part of the `IAppDomainSetup` interface.

Comment: It didnt work. It didnt ahve the same effect as the two old lines. My dlls are still locked down when you using your suggestion.

Comment: Inetresting :) I will stick to the obsolete methods until it becomes a problem.

Comment: The code provided didnt work. I ran into problems using the two orginal obsolete methods when my application was deployed. It could not start. Its starting fine on developer machine but installed click once app didnt start. System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException

Comment: @pksorensen Boo. The only way I have been able to do pluggable DLLs like that was with manually creating AppDomains, but that is a whole other can of worms. Good luck. There are reasons that DLLs are locked while the program is running.

Comment: Ye i know. I just want the end result and creating a shell application just to create appdomains sux. But thanks for the assist.